# Dojo ValidationTextBox displays missingMessage on Enter

Tags: dojo

I am new to Dojo so please bear with me. I created a widget inheriting from ValidationTextBox and SimpleTextarea:

```
define([
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'dijit/form/ValidationTextBox',
    'dijit/form/SimpleTextarea'
    ],
    function (declare, ValidationTextBox, SimpleTextarea) {
        return declare([
            ValidationTextBox,
            SimpleTextarea
        ], {
        });
    }
);
```

I use it in a html page like this:

```
                    <textarea   class="dijitTextBox dijitTextArea dijitTextBoxHover dijitTextAreaHover dijitHover"
                                data-dojo-attach-point="dutyReasonTextarea"
                                data-dojo-type="aysist/widgets/common/ValidationTextArea"
                                data-dojo-props="placeholder: '${nls.employee.agenda.duty_hour_reason}',required: true, missingMessage:'missingMessage: ${nls.employee.agenda.missing_duty_reason_error}', invalidMessage:'The value is not valid'"
                                value=""></textarea>
```

As I type in the textbox, no error message pops up. But as soon as I type an Enter, I get the invalidMessage. Also, I expect a red border to appear on error.
What am I doing wrong?

[image: invalidMessage displayed after typing Enter]

Comment: the best way to handle (according to me) is to use pattern to accept or reject the characters you want.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the erroneous invalidMessage add a hack: an empty invalidMessage attribute to data-dojo-props. Like this:

```
<textarea ... data-dojo-props="...,invalidMessage:''"value=""></textarea>
```

To get the contents of the validatorTextarea widget to validate correctly so there is no red border when you add contents with a newline character use a validator in the custom ValidatorTextarea widget. Like his:

```
validator: function(value) {
    return value && value.length > 0
}
```

Hth somebody!